# Use multiple exchanges with StreamBridge

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

From the definition of StreamBridge there is no implementation for defining a RabbitMQ exchange.

Is there a way to programmatically set the destination (i.e., RabbitMQ exchanage) and not just the binding with StreamBridge?

Answer (score 0):

`StreamBridge` (SB) is not a general purpose utility class to interact with underlying messaging system (e.g., RabbitMq). It is however a general purpose utility class to interact with the binder which connect messaging system to your application. So yes there is a method in SB to specify which binder should be used to send a message, but that is where it stops.

You can use RabbotTemplate from Spring-AMQP project to have have that level of granularity, but that is out of scope of spring-cloud-stream.